# .show() an element conditional on values of field in the same form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form (below) with one text input `id="age"` and two radio inputs `id="radio_value_1"` and `id="radio_value_2"`. The page will load with the two radios hidden by `.hide()`. I would like the first to `.show()` again if the value in the text field is above 5 and the second if the value is above 10. I tried with

```
 $('#age').click(function(){
    // 
     });
```

but the effect is that as soon as the field is clicked the page disappears.

```
<form name='survey' action='' method='post'>

Age:<br>
<input type="text" id="age" name="Q1">

<br>

<table border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="25">
    <label>
    <input id="radio_value_1" name="Q2" value="1" type="radio">
    </label>
      </td>
      <td>First choice</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="25">
    <label>
    <input id="radio_value_2" name="Q2" value="2" type="radio">
    </label>
      </td>
      <td>Second choice</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<input type='submit' value=SUBMIT>
</form>

<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js'></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( '#radio_value_1' ).hide();
    $( '#radio_value_2' ).hide();
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
$("#age").on("input", function(){
    var val = parseInt( $(this).val() );
    $( '#radio_value_1' ).toggle( val > 5 );
    $( '#radio_value_2' ).toggle( val > 10 );
});
```

Comment: Can you post some code/share a jsfiddle or something with the checkboxes so I can help diagnose?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this too as your whole script .

```
$("#age").on("input", function(){
    $( '#radio_value_1' ).hide();
    $( '#radio_value_2' ).hide();
    if($(this).val()>5&&$(this).val()<10) {
        $( '#radio_value_1' ).toggle();
    }
    if($(this).val()>10) {
        $( '#radio_value_2' ).toggle();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using .click() use .change()

you can try something like this,

```
$("#age").change(function(){
      var text_value = parseInt( $(this).val(), 10 );
      if( text_value > 5 ){
            $( '#radio_value_1' ).show();
      }
      else{
            $( '#radio_value_1' ).hide();
      }
      if( text_value > 10 ){
            $( '#radio_value_2' ).show();
      }
      else{
            $( '#radio_value_2' ).hide();
      }
});
```